# SQL Stored Procedure select returns only table without values

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

My  SQL stored procedure with select returns only table without values,it just shows the column name without any values in it ? Why? How to retrieve values of the table using stored procedure?

```
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/79Gt2.jpg
USE [Mobile]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[UserRegisterproc]    Script Date: 05/23/2016 10:51:47 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[UserRegisterproc]
@mode int=null,
@id int=null,
@name varchar(30)=null,
@usertype varchar(30)=null,
@username varchar(30),
@password varchar(30),
@email varchar(30)=null,
@mob varchar(30)=null
as begin
if (@mode =1) 
begin
insert into UserRegister (name,usertype,username,password ,email,mob )values(@name,@usertype,@username,@password ,@email,@mob )
end
if(@mode =2) 
begin
select * from UserRegister 
end
if (@mode =3) 
begin
update UserRegister  set name=@name,usertype=@usertype,password=@password ,email=@email,mob=@mob where username=@username
end
if(@mode =4) 
begin
delete from UserRegister where username=@username
end
if(@mode =5) 
begin
  select * from UserRegister where username =@username and password =@password 
  end
if(@mode =6) 
begin
  select * from UserRegister where usertype= @usertype
  end
  if(@mode =7) 
begin
  select * from UserRegister where usertype  =@usertype  and username =@username 
  end
end
```

Comment: The query used in the SP did not return any rows that's why. Please post the SP.

Comment: Do you want us to guess?

Comment: Edit your answer please and add it there in the right format.

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (Most of them have vendor specific stored procedures...)

Comment: What happens when you query `select * from UserRegister where usertype='1'`?

Comment: it get executed correctly.but within a sp it just displays the table format without items

Comment: You are passing in 6 to `@mode`  do you have `if (@mode=6)` in your stored proc?

Comment: yes i do have mode 6

Comment: just for making it clear i have used the mode as 1 now but actually in my project the mode is 6 so it shows  an empty table ,where as  for simple select statement it shows  the right o/p

Comment: Then show the actual code that is not working for you.

Comment: please post sample content data (not just one column, all the columns) and actual table structure with datatypes. please supply expected result sample with data (not just one column, all the columns).

Comment: none of select statements with where condition return table with values

Comment: Then that suggests you have no data that matches the parameters you are passing in.

Comment: select name from UserRegister where usertype='Staff'  ;Simple select Statements retrieves data from table

Comment: Does this show any data?  `exec UserRegisterproc 6,null,null,'Staff',null,null,null`

Comment: yea it shows the result.tanQ bro

Answer (score 1):

1) try to run

`select * from UserRegister`
 to make sure table have data

if data exists

2) You should try to run with
`select * from UserRegister where usertype  ='abc'  and username ='abc'`

**abc** is real data from UserRegister table